# Need to find the date when I make my distro-upgrade

Tags: debian, package-management

I made a backup from my Systempartition (stretch) without clearing  the destination partition, where a Jessie installation was. I will later identify the folders and files, that are missing in the System.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

Found a possibilty. I thought it is a good idea to look in /var/log/apt

```
find /var/log/apt/ -name '*.gz' -exec zgrep 'linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64' {} +
```

This was the kernel that cames in during the upgrade to stretch.

In my case with

```
zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
```

`